# How can i find a specific word (such as Norway), in a LinkedIn profile. I am trying to find it in inspect

Tags: google-chrome, inspect

How can i find a specific word (such as Norway), in a LinkedIn profile. I am trying to find it in inspect. I am trying to find all the people that went to Norway, but sometimes it doesnt say in their main summary, but hidden in their full summary.

Any other suggestions, are welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no designated area where people would put where they've been. They could put it anywhere in their profile. You can simply search the page in the Inspector, with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Windows) shortcuts and keep pressing enter until you find. It's tediuous and there's no guarantee all the content has been loaded at any given time, e.g. requires AJAX requests etc.

However, if you want to get this kind of information in a more structured and automated way, I recommend checking out the [LinkedIn API](https://developer.linkedin.com/). You can either use the [REST API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api), which requires OAuth, or the [JavaScript SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk), which requires an API key. The latter would be my preferred choice.

The API provides a list of [basic profile fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile) you can get back from the JSON response.